# 6 запросов callback-функции query

Tags: javascript, jquery

Доброго времени суток. Столкнулся с такой проблемой в jquery. Необходимо по завершении функции клонировать изображение и разместить его по координатом старого. Но вместо одного клона, я получаю сразу 6 т.к. callback в animate() вызывается как раз 6 раз.

```js
function slideAuth(){
 $('#logInBlock').contents().css({zIndex:2,position:'relative'});
 $('#logInBlock').contents().animate({marginLeft:'-450px',opacity:'hide'},500,function(){
  /*var newLogo=$('#mainLogo').clone();
  var oldLogoPos=$('#mainLogo').offset();
  $(newLogo).css({top:oldLogoPos.top+'px',left:oldLogoPos.left+'px',position:'fixed'});
  $("body").append(newLogo);*/
  console.log(0);
 });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

> complete
>
> Type: Function()
>
> A function to call once the animation is complete, called once per matched element.

```
function slideAuth(){
  var count = $('#logInBlock').contents().length;
  var index = 0;
  $('#logInBlock').contents().css({zIndex:2,position:'relative'});
  $('#logInBlock').contents().animate({marginLeft:'-450px',opacity:'hide'},500,function(){
    if (count == ++index) {    
      var newLogo=$('#mainLogo').clone();
      var oldLogoPos=$('#mainLogo').offset();
      $(newLogo).css({top:oldLogoPos.top+'px',left:oldLogoPos.left+'px',position:'fixed'});
      $("body").append(newLogo);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Сглупил, только сейчас дошло, что у меня на контент анимация с callback'ом стоит. Но Ваш код тоже не сработал. Count вообще 11 равен. А индекс всего лишь 6.

Answer (score 2):

Проблема решилась добавлением списка элементов, встречающихся в блоке и кодом предыдущего автора. Спасибо.